# Google Earth Engine - getting download URL of reprojected image not working?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, image

I am using the Google Earth Engine Python API.

I'm having a strange issue where when I try to generate a download URL for an image, it works fine.

But when I reproject the image before generating the URL it does not work (gives me a "Site can't be reached" error. Also, when I pass in the desired CRS to the actual function that generates the URL it results in an error and doesn't even run. Here is my code so far:

This works:

```
test_url = test_img.getDownloadURL({
    'image': test_img.serialize(),
    'region': polygon,
    'bands': out_bands,
    'filePerBand': 'false',
    'name': img_name,
})
```

and outputs a URL that works fine.

However when I try this:

```
test_img = test_img.reproject('EPSG:32628')
test_url = test_img.getDownloadURL({
    'image': test_img.serialize(),
    'region': polygon,
    'bands': out_bands,
    'filePerBand': 'false',
    'name': img_name,
})
```

I get a "Site can't be reached" error when I click on the url, it still generates a url but it doesn't work.

When I try this:

```
test_url = test_img.getDownloadURL({
    'image': test_img.serialize(),
    'region': polygon,
    'bands': out_bands,
    'filePerBand': 'false',
    'name': img_name,
    'crs': 'EPSG:32628'
})
```

I get the following error:

```
ee.ee_exception.EEException: The requested image band is too large: was 14801736 bytes per scanline; must be no more than 262144 bytes per scanline.
```

Oddly enough, after doing the reprojection, I can verify manually that the reprojection took place, as all the bands in the image now have the CRS I specified.

Weird...not sure what I'm doing wrong as it seems pretty straightforward.

Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: I believe (not really sure) that the issue is related to not specifying a scale when I reproject, anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I have never gotten getDownloadURL() working and I'm using export.Image.toDrive() as alternative. Perhaps you could use it too.

Comment: thanks, I've considered it. It works fine when i don't attempt a reprojection..but anytime I try to reproject the URL doesn't work anymore..

Answer (score 0):

The CRS that you have specified (EPSG:32628, UTM 28 N) may not be appropriate for your area of interest. UTM 28 N is appropriate for longitudes such as typical for the west coast of West Africa or for Island. Likely your area of interest is at a very different location.

Comment: that is exactly where my polygon is defined